# Bootstrap mobile navbar cuts off

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site with Bootstrap. For some reason, the mobile navbar cuts off "Menu" as you can see here:[image]

I'm just using normal Bootstrap responsive code for the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">Menu</a>       
                            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
```

Trouble is, if I add any sort of padding, it adds too much padding to the non-mobile navbar and makes it look weird. Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: Noone can helo you with this in it's current form. Either show us a link with it on or paste a basic, broken, example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your theme.css file you have:

```
.navbar-inner {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: -20px 0; <-- *
}
```

* This is putting your inner navbar off the top of the page. Either remove it or change it to -10px;